# Area51 onebox ignores the closed status of proposals

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, chat

When you link [this closed proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42837/italian-arts-and-stuff) in chat you get [this onebox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5721690#5721690):

> *1* **Italian arts and stuff**
>
> Proposed Q&A site for surfer dudes that like to think and stuff
>
> Currently in definition.

The onebox offers no hint that the proposal is closed. Could one be added pretty please?

Comment: NO! Oh, you said "please". Okay.

Comment: `There is no hint that the proposal is closed` Description not enough for you? ;P

Comment: It has "[closed]" added to the name of the proposal itself. Or was that not there at the time you posted the question?

Comment: @YannisRizos Where is it in the onebox?

Comment: @badp Heh, it was a joke, what I meant was that a proposal with a description "for surfer dudes that like to think and stuff" is bound to be closed...

Comment: @YannisRizos It might not be closed yet, however, and require a flag/close vote.

Comment: @badp I know, I know, it was a joke! ;) I'm your single up vote, don't make me regret it ;P <-- also a joke...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proposals that were closed *after* they had been launched (the so-called "failed proposals") were already handled correctly. Now this is also the case for those that were closed even before that:

[image: screenshot of two oneboxes of closed proposals; one before, one after launch.]