# ThinkGeek onebox support for chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

I think it would be fun to have ThinkGeek products onebox in the chat system. 
We already Have other shopping sites like Amazon there, and this site is directed towards 'geeks'. Albeit this wouldn't be the most useful onebox, I do think It would be fun.

***Please?!***

Comment: [You didn't say please.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142969/area51-onebox-ignores-the-closed-status-of-proposals#comment405930_142969)

Comment: @YannisRizos There we go.

Answer (score 17):

I like this idea, but would take it one step further.

ThinkGeek has fairly complete OpenGraph metadata on it, i.e.:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="product"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Star Trek Cookie Cutters"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/ed0a/?cpg=fbl_ed0a"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.thinkgeek.com/images/products/frontsquare/ed0a_star_trek_cookie_cutters.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="ThinkGeek"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Ready to blast your baking into the 23rd century, this series of five cookie cutters features the symbols of the Federation and Klingon Empire, the U.S.S. Dessert Sur... Enterprise, a phaser, and a Live Long and Nom hand... (Prosper, sorry, prosper.)"/>
```

If someone were to, say, implement generic support for oneboxing OpenGraph data, all we would need is some way for the community and/or mods to vet domains with OpenGraph support to be added to , then we wouldn't need to pester devs with every little site we think it would be cute/fun/useful to have oneboxed.

Comment: I've implemented this generic-support [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178824/support-for-oneboxing-opengraph-data-in-the-chats/182582#182582). I've hesitated to include html generation due to lack of knowledge regarding what SO uses