# Add Wiktionary to Chat Onebox

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, onebox

Chat already oneboxes Wikipedia links, so it would surely be quick and easy to add support for other MediaWiki sites. I'd particularly like to see Wiktionary added.

[Please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142973/thinkgeek-onebox-support-for-chat#comment405943_142973).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Apparently](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18238107#18238107), Wiktionary now [works in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18224849#18224849). Enjoy!

Although....apparently it doesn't work all that well -- see the [follow-up question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243503/266359).

Comment: Ok, I [cheated](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18243512#18243512) ....but so what? :P