# Wiktionary oneboxing badly

Tags: bug, chat, onebox

[The Wiktionary oneboxing](/a/242363) [doesn't capture all the definitions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18590238#18590238). (I seem to recall seeing an instance where it captured something that wasn't a definition, too.) And the definitions it does capture can be in any language, but it doesn't mention what language they're in.

---

Here's the relevant part of the layout of an [English Wiktionary](//en.wiktionary.org) entry:

- The language name appears in an HTML `H2` element (in `==...==` code in the wiki markup, on a line by itself). The page is divided by such elements (i.e., all Latin-language definitions appear under the `==Latin==` code). There are no other `==` headers on the page, though there are some `H2`s (generated by the software, so they don't appear in the wiki markup).
- The definitions are lines that start with `\#+[^*:]` (in regex), i.e. any number of `#`s followed by anything but a `*` or `:`. That's in the wiki markup; in HTML it translates to: an `LI` element in an `OL`, but not any `UL` or `DL` contained within that `LI`.

`?action=raw` on a Wiktionary URL will give you the wiki markup instead of the HTML.